# Why image don't show on from application

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

My code

```
private void button_click(object sender,RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    path = "C:\\1.jpg"
    BitmapImage imageBitmap = new BitmapImage();
    imageBitmap.BeginInit();
    imageBitmap.UriSource = new Uri(path,UriKind.Relative);
    image.Source = imageBitmap ;
}
```

I want to when I click a button from application will show a image.
(I use .NET Framework 4.6)
thank you.

Comment: What behavior you are seeing? Are you seeing any error? The path is not relative. Try passing urikind.absolute

Comment: When I build a project do not show,when I click a button the image still  do not show. And don't have error. Now I try urikind.absolute It work Thank you very much ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should call `EndInit()` on the `imageBitmap`.

```
private void button_click(object sender,RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   path = "C:\\1.jpg"
   BitmapImage imageBitmap = new BitmapImage();
   imageBitmap.BeginInit();
   imageBitmap.UriSource = new Uri(path, UriKind.Absolute);
   imageBitmap.EndInit();
   image.Source = imageBitmap;
}
```

Or shorter, by using another `BitmapImage` constructor and no redundant `UriKind`:

```
image.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(path));
```

Comment: And the uriKind is not relative